# VB.net Enable Camera and Microphone access

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I am using WebView2 and would like to enable Microphone and Camera access by default. I didn't find much resources about that and tried several things but was unable to get that to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.permissionrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1018-prerelease

Comment: Unable to get it to work isn't overly helpful.  Any chance you could perhaps update you question with the code of your best attempt and a clear explanation of how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: In Windows applications should ask for permission, if they want camera and microphone, no different in `WebView2`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow camera and microphone without the default dialog to show up and ask the user for permission follow these steps:

After WebView2 has been initialized:

```
webView2.CoreWebView2.PermissionRequested += WebView2_PermissionRequested;
```

Add your event handler:

```
private void WebView2_PermissionRequested(object obj, CoreWebView2PermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PermissionKind == CoreWebView2PermissionKind.Microphone || args.PermissionKind == CoreWebView2PermissionKind.Camera)
        {
            args.State = CoreWebView2PermissionState.Allow;
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```